# Como habilitar e desabilitar botão a partir do onclick ou onchange do select

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Eu já fiz isso com o rádio button, mas estou com problemas para fazer isso a parti de um select. Ao selecionar qualquer funcionário, deve habilitar e quando seleciona  que representa nenhum funcionário, irá desabilitar o botão.

```
<form action="questao2.php" method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <select>
        <option name="ativo" value="--" onchange="if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled==false){document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=true}"/> --</option>
        <option name="ativo" value="FUNCIONARIO1" onchange="if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled==true{document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=false}"/>FUNCIONÁRIO 1</option>
     </select>
 <button id="avancar" type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Avançar</button>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

---

```
<form action="teste.php" method="post">
  <fieldset> Sim ou não? <label class="radio">
      <input name="ativo" type="radio" value="SIM" onclick="if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled==true){document.getEleme‌​ntById('avancar').disabled=false}"/>SIM</label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input name="ativo" type="radio" value="NAO" onclick="if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled==true){document.getEleme‌​ntById('avancar').disabled=false}"/>NÃO</label>
    <button id="avancar" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Avançar</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: <form action="questao2.php" method="post">
   <fieldset>
      <select>
     <option name="ativo" value="--" onchange="if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled==false){document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=true}"/> --</option>
     <option name="ativo" value="FUNCIONARIO1" onchange="if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled==true{document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=false}"/>FUNCIONÁRIO 1</option>
     </select>
 <button id="avancar" type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Avançar</button>

</fieldset>
</form>

Comment: pode colocar o código do radio button? melhor do que fazer um a um é melhor criar um código mais geral que funciona para muitos elementos. Mas para isso tem de colocar o código todo relevante a esta pergunta.

Comment: <form action="teste.php" method="post">
       <fieldset>
Sim ou não?
 <label class="radio"><input name="ativo" type="radio" value="SIM" onclick="if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled==true){document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=false}"/>SIM</label>
 <label class="radio"><input name="ativo" type="radio" value="NAO" onclick="if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled==true){document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=false}"/>NÃO</label>
 <button id="avancar" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Avançar</button></fieldset>
</form>
Obrg @Sergio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O evento **onchange** deve ficar no **< select onchange="acao()">**

Veja se isto resolve seu problema:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function habilitaBtn () {
            var op = document.getElementById("opcao").value;

            if(op == "--")
            {
                if(!document.getElementById('avancar').disabled) document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=true;              
            }

            else if(op == "FUNCIONARIO1")
            {
                if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled) document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=false;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <body>
    <form action="questao2.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <select onchange="habilitaBtn()" id="opcao">
            <option name="ativo" value="--"/> --</option>
            <option name="ativo" value="FUNCIONARIO1"/>FUNCIONÁRIO 1</option>
        </select>
        <button id="avancar" type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" >Avançar</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito.
Obrigado @user11795.

Comment: Eu fiz uma pequena melhoria que se for igual à "--", desabilita e se for diferente de vazio, habilita.
Criei um arquivo javascript.

Comment: Olha isso, @Irpinheiro.

function habilitaBTN()
            {
                var op = document.getElementById("opcao").value;
                if(op == "--")
                {
                    if(!document.getElementById('avancar').disabled)document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=true;
                }
                else if (!op == "")
                {
                    if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled)document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=false;
                }
            }

Comment: @fabricio_wm pelo q entendi vc só precisa desabilitar o botão quando for igual '--' então eu alterei o código, da uma olhada e vê se faz sentido pra vc.

`function habilitaBTN() {
var op = document.getElementById("opcao").value;
 if(op == "--"){
 if(!document.getElementById('avancar').disabled)     document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=true;
} 
 else {           if(document.getElementById('avancar').disabled)
document.getElementById('avancar').disabled=false;
}
}`

Assim como foi dito na outra resposta é bom separar em camadas sua aplicação,separe **JS**,**CSS** e **HTML**.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui fica uma sugestão, já depois de ter aceite uma das respostas.
(Link: http://jsfiddle.net/AvXws/)

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('form select, form input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', verificar);
}

function buscaBotao(elInicial) {

    // ir buscar o field set mais correspondente
    var fieldset = elInicial.parentElement;
    while (fieldset.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'fieldset') fieldset = fieldset.parentNode;

    // ir buscar o botao
    var botao = fieldset.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

    // devolver o elemento
    return botao;
}

function verificar(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var value = el.value || el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
    var botao = buscaBotao(el);
    botao.disabled = !value;
}
```

Esta sugestão melhora o seu código nestes pontos:

- retira o javascript misturado no HTML. Isso é má prática e fica dificil de perceber.
- muda ID do botão para class, no caso de ter vários na mesma página isso daria erro.

Para ele funcionar deve colocar o javascript no final do body, ou envolvendo numa função `window.onload=function(){ ...codigoaqui...};`

Repare no jsFiddle que coloquei como o código fica mais limpo (HTML sem javascript no meio) e mais fácil de manter.