# Como usar button para navegação entre páginas

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um botão que estou usando um link conforme código abaixo:

```
<button id="avancar" type="submit" disabled="disabled" class="btn-primary">
    <a href="teste.php">Avançar</a>
</button>
```

Esse botão é desabilitado, caso não seja selecionado nenhuma opção.
Não sei se essa é a forma correta, mas ao clicar no botão desabilitado, está avançando para a próxima página.

Como eu devo proceder?  
Se eu colocar `required` no select, não funciona mesmo que eu deixe o option em branco e o value em branco.

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/9w2zW/

Link do tópico sobre habilitar e desabilitar botão:
[Como habilitar e desabilitar botão a partir do onclick ou onchange do select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22439/129)

Obrigado.

Comment: Quer re-carregar a página ou abrir o novo conteudo na mesma página? No segundo caso pode colocar o HTML respectivo?

Comment: @Sergio O código completo não coube aqui, então eu fiz esse link.
http://jsfiddle.net/9w2zW/
Obrigado.

Comment: Já que o botão será habilitado por JS, troque o <a> por um <span> e faça a requisição pelo próprio JS, seja AJAX populando algum elemento ou um window.location.

Comment: @fabricio_wm, vou volocar o jsFiddle na pergunta (na proxima vez pode clicar em "editar" para melhorar a pergunta com mais informaJão). Entretanto pode responder à minha pergunta no primeiro comentário?

Comment: Poxa @Sergio, me desculpe mas eu achei que vc já tinha entendido que é para navegação já que você participou do post anterior.
Obrigado.

Comment: @fabricio_wm, eu percebo que é para navegação. O que eu ainda não sei é se quer carregar somente uma `div` com o novo conteúdo, ou se quer carregar a página toda com o novo conteudo.

Comment: Me desculpe. 
Agora ficou mais claro. Era página, mas se tiver como carregar div's, fica melhor ainda.
Obrigado.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto <br />
Como eu faço a parte do JavaScript ou Ajax?

Comment: @fabricio_wm, você precisa de usar ajax. Está a usar alguma biblioteca como MooTools ou jQuery?

Comment: Pode ser Jquery.  <br />
Mas eu sou iniciante.  <br />
Obrigado.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto ou Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui fica um exemplo típico de AJAX do jQuery, e o que você precisa:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    var form_url = $(this).attr("action"); // ou somente teste.php no seu caso
    var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

    $("#loadingimg").show();

    $.ajax({
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function(returnhtml){  
            $("#loadingimg").hide();                         
            $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
        }           
    });    

});
```

A primeira parte deste código não tem ainda a ver com o ajax. É um "event handler" que intercepta o momento/evento em que a form é submetida.

O código `e.preventDefault();` pára essa ação. O `e` é o objeto-evento que vai ser parado, ou seja a página não vai recarregar.

As linhas que se seguem são para preparar respectivamente os dados a enviar, o url do lado do servidor, o tipo de método (tipicamente POST ou GET).

A linha `$("#loadingimg").show();` é opcional e é para o caso de ter uma imagem, ou texto que queira mostrar enquanto a ligação é feita so para o utilizador saber que está a haver processamento no servidor.

Com a chamada deste método `$.ajax({` começa a parte do AJAX.

O ajax é exatamnente para carregar conteudo do servidor sem ter de fazer refresh à página. Aqui os parametros defenidos em variáveis em cima vão ser usados.

A parte talvez mais importante, é `success: function(returnhtml){`. Aqui é a chamada callback. A função que corre quando o pedido AJAX recebe dados de volta do servidor. O html é passado na variável `returnhtml`.

Neste exemplo, a primeira linha esconde a imagem que estava a mostrar durante o pedido. A segunda linha é o que você procura, ou seja `$("#result").html(returnhtml);` que vai inserir o novo conteudo no elemento DOM com a ID `result`

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54604/discussion-on-answer-by-sergio-como-usar-button-para-navegacao-entre-paginas)